# Chef-client using docker container ID when Syncing Cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to docker and chef. I have a chef server in a docker container and managed to bootstrap an AWS machine from there. When I call chef client on the AWS node it tries to connect to the container ID (3442f619df6f) instead of the AWS machine that hosts the docker image and fails:

```
Error Syncing Cookbooks:
================================================================================

Networking Error:
-----------------

Error connecting to https://**3442f619df6f**/bookshelf/organization-00000000000000000000000000000000/checksum-cessKeyId=bd33427fd1d9ef165ef9e70120064ec - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Your chef_server_url may be misconfigured, or the network could be down.
```

#### Relevant Config Settings:

```
chef_server_url  "https://mymackine.compute.amazonaws.com:443"
```

How can I configure the chef-client to use the AWS hostname instead of the docker ID?

Answer (score 0):

We reeeeally don't support running Chef Server inside Docker, please follow the actual install instructions.